# Nuget package - Interfaces and its implementation in separate class libraries

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I have a question related to NuGet package..

Can I have a class library that has Interfaces only and it's implementation is in separate library? Additionally, can I mark the implementation internal instead of public?

Comment: Actually you can try by yourself. The class library  on your local is no different whit NuGet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Can I have a class library that has Interfaces only and it's implementation is in separate library?`

Yes. You can have a class library with only interface class
[image]

And have the other class library which reference to that interface library and implement it
[image]

`Additionally, can I mark the implementation internal instead of public?`

Because the interface method is public so when your class implement the interface method you need to mark it public so the answer is No.

But you can do [explicit-interface-implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) then user only can call the interface method by define the instance type to that interface.

```
using System;

namespace InterfaceLibrary
{
    public interface IInterface
    {
        public void Do();
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using InterfaceLibrary;

namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public class Class : IInterface
    {
        void IInterface.Do()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do");
        }
    }
}
```

```
// This can find the Do method
IInterface class1 = new Class();
class1.Do();

// This can't find the Do method
Class class2 = new Class();
class2.Do();
```

Comment: Thank You @MichaelMao

Comment: @bankerbox Don't know what you really want to do could you explain more?

Comment: I just needed to know if Interface and its implementation can be split in different class libraries if I have to make a nuget package

Comment: How about internal part?